# Matrix 2x2 named A

Tags: matrices

$A^2 + A - 6I = 0$

A= $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$

I was asked to find
$a + d$, and $ad - bc$

$a+d>0$

What i get is 
$A^2$ = $\begin{bmatrix}a^2+bc & ab + bd\\ac+dc & bc+d^2\end{bmatrix}$

I get
$a^2+bc+a=6, $

$ab+bd+b = 0,$

$bc+d^2+d=6, $

$ac+dc+c=0$

I get a=-1/2, d=-1/2

Why i get wrong answer? Please help me?

Comment: The matrix operations are fine, I think. So you should take another look at how you solve the equations

Comment: Using eigenvalues, it's easy to verify that we must have
$$
(a+b,ad - bc) \in \{(4,4),(-6,9),(1,-6)\}
$$

Comment: Note:  you were asked for the trace and determinant

Comment: It's easy to confuse the signs in $A^2-tr(A)A+\det(A)I=0$, but if we have $A^2+A-6I=0$ then we have the pair $(-1,-6)$ and not $(1,-6)$?

Comment: Your equations are correct, so clearly you did something wrong when you solved them. If you want someone to tell you what that is, you’ll have to show your work instead of making everyone guess.

Comment: Hey. Why using elimination from the equation i get a+d = -1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that
$$(A+3I)(A-2I)=0$$
so the matrix
$$A=2I=\pmatrix{2&0\\0&2}$$
is a valid such $A$.

Comment: Why i cant use standard algebra for this?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter $(a,b,c,d)=(2,0,0,2)$ is a valid solution to your set of simultaneous equations but there is more than one solution to these equations.

Answer (score 1):

"*I was asked to find $a + d$, and $ad - bc$*".

Note that these are the trace of $A$ and the determinant of $A$. Here we have several possibilities under the assumption  that $A^2+A-6I=0$, i.e.,
$$
(A+3I)(A-2I)=0.
$$
This gives three possibilities: $a+d=4$ and $ad-bc=4$, or 
$a+d=-6$ and $ad-bc=9$, or finally $a+d=-1$ and $ad-bc=-6$ because of Cayley-Hamilton
$$
A^2-tr(A)A+\det(A)I=0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in the characteristic equation of a matrix $A$ like$$|\lambda I-A|=\lambda^n+a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}+\cdots +a_1\lambda+a_0=0$$we have $$a_0=|-A|=(-1)^n |A|\\a_{n-1}=\text{tr}(A)$$so here we have three possibilities in the characteristic equation of $A$ $$\lambda^2+\lambda -6=0\\\lambda-2=0\\\lambda+3=0$$which lead to $$n=2\\|A|=ad-bc=-6\quad,\quad \text{tr}(A)=a+d=-1\\|A|=4\quad,\quad \text{tr}(A)=4\\|A|=9\quad,\quad \text{tr}(A)=-6$$